# How to add new autoupgrade item to installscript MSI project using commandline

Tags: windows-installer, upgrade, build-automation, installshield-2012, installscript-msi

I am using InstallShield 2012 to create a installscript MSI project to create patch installer for my product. I am planning to automate my product build process to create patches using ISCMBuild.exe.

While creating new patch, i want to add list of all previous setups under upgrades view to support Upgrade scenarios from the previous patch levels.

Each time i create a new patch, i have to add previous patch setup file details in upgrades section.
Now, i want to know if there is anyway to add this entry in upgrades view from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve this using Install Shield Automation Interface "ISWiProject" object.
Hope it helps others who are looking for the similar stuff.